# Access Error 3813 - Open Query in Design/SQL View

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database I have inherited, and was making changes to a query today to try and pull in some new data. I botched the design change and pulled in a table so large that opening the query now gives me an error 3813. Text as follows:

> The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2 GB), or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result.

I would obviously like to fix this query, but attempting to open it in design view makes the DB not respond, followed by the same error.

Is there a way I can force this open in SQL or Design view to fix it? Seems weird that it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Rename one of the tables/queries used in query, it will force Access to open it in SQL mode after error message.Direct renaming may not help because Access updates object name in related queries, so the best way - create a copy, then delete original table/query.

To unload Access object to text you can use `SaveAsText`:

```
Application.SaveAsText acQuery, "MyQyeryName", "C:\TEMP\query.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could run some VBA to send the SQL of the your broken query to the immediate window and then copy that to a new query and essentially start over:

```vb
Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef

Set qDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myBrokenQueryName")
Debug.Print qDef.SQL
```